# HTML5 CANVAS AS3 JAVASCRIPT go to the next frame movie clip inside a movie clip in animate cc

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3, flash

in my process to create a UI, I was stuck quite early by not being able to tell a movie clip inside a movie clip to go forward a single frame during a mouseover (over another, different symbol)

basically I want to hover over an area (which I created using a button symbol with just the hit area marked:

[screenshot](https://gyazo.com/8a9a920b43a41c19434617999511952b)

and while you're hovered over it, a movie clip inside a movie clip will go forward a single frame. the mouseover is working, I tested it with an alert.

this is my code:

```
var frequency = 15;
stage.enableMouseOver(frequency);
this.sirtonim.addEventListener("mouseover", fl_MouseOverHandler.bind(this));

function fl_MouseOverHandler()
{
    // Start your custom code
    // This example code displays the words "Moused over" in the Output panel.

    this.inter.highlight1.gotoAndStop(1);

    // End your custom code
}
```

sirtonim = instance name of the button

inter = instance name of the first movie clip

highlight1 = instance name of the movie clip inside the movie clip

thanks ahead! (I tried changing gotoAndStop to (2) as well, it didn't work)

Comment: Can you provide some more information? Where is that animation stored exactly? Is `highlight1` being moved/animated within `inter`? In that case, `inter` needs to play and not `highlight1`. Also, `gotoAndStop(1)` will not do anything in most cases because `1` is the default frame for a new Movieclip.

Comment: I've solved it overtly by placing the button INSIDE the first movie clip, and then using the same code with 'this.highlight1.gotoAndStop(1)' @jens108